# using callback with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

js and now I am facing a problem with my app.js 
the problem is I want to call a function before the route root is executed 
the function I want to call is as follow:

```
function findCats(){
  var cats;
  Categorie.find({}, function(err, foundCats){
    if(err){
      console.log("Error can not find the categories ==> "+err);
    }else{
      this.cats = foundCats;
    }
  });
  return this.cats;
}
```

it finds a category from a database and send the returns the result
the route root should use this result before execute res.render()
this is my route root

```
 app.get("/",function(req, res){

           res.render("landing",{cats: findCats()});

 });
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback to your findCats function

```
function findCats(callback) {
  var cats;
  Categorie.find({}, function(err, foundCats){
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error can not find the categories ==> " + err);
    } else {
      callback(foundCats);
    }
  });
}
```

Then send your response within that callback

```
 app.get("/",function(req, res){
     findCats((cats) => {
         res.render("landing", {cats});
     });
 });
```